# Android 11 camera not working on webview : Unsupported mime image/vnd.android.heic

Tags: java, android, dart, webview, angular-dart

I'm using webview to show my webapp. Unfortunaly I can not display camera from WebView. I would like to use the camera to scan a QrCode (code is web side and is working on Chrome).

Permissions seem rightly setted but I have a warning about an Unsupported mime type.

The device used runs on Android 11 (API 30).

I tried a lot of solution found on documentation or other posts, but nothing seems change the situation.

My webapplication is written with AngularDart and here how I display the camera in my Dart code :

```
<video
  #video
  autoplay
  class="video-container"
></video>
```

```
  @override
  void ngAfterViewInit() {
    VideoElement video = document.querySelector("video");
    window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({'video': true}).then((stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
      videoStream = stream;
      //this._instascanService.startCapture(video, this.handleQrCodeScanned);
    });
  }
```

Here the android webview code :

```
...
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
...

mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // Grant permissions for cam
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(request.getOrigin().toString().equals("https://mywebapp.com/")) { //In my code, this value is correct
                            Log.d(TAG, "GRANTED"); //Displayed rightly in console
                            request.grant(request.getResources());
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "DENIED");
                            request.deny();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
...
...
```

The manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

And finally the console output :

```
I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
D/MainActivity: onPermissionRequest
D/MainActivity: https://mywebapp.com/
D/MainActivity: GRANTED
E/cr_VideoCapture: CameraDevice.StateCallback onOpened
W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime image/vnd.android.heic
W/Gralloc4: allocator 3.x is not supported
W/et.mainactivity: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
E/cr_VideoCapture: cameraDevice encountered an error
```

On my screen I see a grey screen with a big black "play icon".

If I forgot some important information, don't hesitate.

Just for information, before the current dart code, I was using instascan.js (with interop) but I had the same error. I make a simplified code to reproduce the issue and find easily the solution (or not).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: These might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47167668/8745788 https://stackoverflow.com/a/42113298/8745788

Comment: @Mattia thanks for your answer. My certificat SSL is correctly installed on my server. I tried the "onReceivedSslError" solution to be sure, but it's still not working.